# Using array_count _values with JSON array

Tags: php

I have a script that I am updating from using XML to JSON. This script worked fine when using XML. I am having some problems using it with JSON. I can echo the variable inside the loop and it returns values so I know it is parsing it correctly. Unfortunately it is failing to count all the values and returning me a single number for to total number of values. Is there something different I need to do when using JSON than XML.

Here is two snippets one is the working solution using XML as the data source. The other is the solution I am unable to get working with JSON which is what I need to get working. I do must mention in the JSON solution I am filtering the values prior to the loop where in the XML solution it is filtered post loop. So in the JSON solution it should be pretty simple. Just count the number of values returned. I am just not able to get it to work. I tried count() and that just returns 1 for value. So I decided to plug that into the array_count_values and let it count those integers and that didn't work ether.

XML Solution - WORKS

```
    // Lets parse the feed
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($data3);

$events = [];
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1", "event") as $event) {
    $events[] = $event->nodeValue;
}

    $counts = array_count_values($events);//lets count the results
    $value = @$counts["Tornado Warning"] + @$counts["Severe Thunderstorm Warning"] + @$counts["Flash Flood Warning"] + @$counts["Flood Warning"] + @$counts["Tropical Storm Warning"] + @$counts["Hurricane Warning"];


$showCounts = '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle severe-icon__tornado"></i> NATIONAL WARNINGS <span class="badge" style="margin-bottom:2px;">' . $value. '</span>';

$showTitle = '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle severe-icon__tornado"></i> NATIONAL WARNINGS';


if($value == "0") {
    echo $showTitle;
} else {
    echo $showCounts;
}
```

JSON Solution - DOESN'T WORK

```
$str = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$o=json_decode($str,true);
$features=$o['features'];

//Lets filter the response to get only the values we want
$filtered= array_filter($features,function($el){
    $alerts = array('Tornado Warning', 'Severe Thunderstorm Warning', 'Hurricane Warning', 'Tropical Storm Warning', 'Flash Flood Warning', 'Flood Warning');
    return in_array($el['properties']['event'],$alerts);});

$events = [];

//Lets loop through the array
foreach($filtered as $currFeature)
{

    $events[] = $currFeature['properties']['event'];

}

    $counts = array_count_values($events);//lets count the results

$showCounts = '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle severe-icon__tornado"></i> NATIONAL WARNINGS <span class="badge" style="margin-bottom:2px;">' . $value. '</span>';

$showTitle = '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle severe-icon__tornado"></i> NATIONAL WARNINGS';

if($counts == "0") {
    echo $showTitle;
} else {
    echo $showCounts;
}
```

Comment: In JSON solution code you use variable $value which is not defined

Comment: Please include some sample input data and your expected result.  This gives your question context and allows volunteers understand your process and to test their codes before posting.

Comment: Your process can be more refined.  If you improve your question, I will be happy to assist you in writing better / more direct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved by adding the following line which I had in the XML solution but left out of the JSON solution. I added this back and now it works great again.

```
$value = @$counts["Tornado Warning"] + @$counts["Severe Thunderstorm Warning"] + @$counts["Flash Flood Warning"] + @$counts["Flood Warning"] + @$counts["Tropical Storm Warning"] + @$counts["Hurricane Warning"];
```